# How to state a combined where-condition on 2 fields in a MS Access query for excluding only those specific rows?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

In a query I would like to exclude the rows that at the same time are;

```
[COMPANY_CODE] In (1001,1002,1003 And [YEAR_MONTH_ID]=201701)
```

Both conditions must be filled before the rows are to be excluded.

I thought of doing something like this, but it gives an error when retriving data from an Oracle table through ODBC connection:

```
WHERE (((([COMPANY_CODE] In (1001,1002,1003)) And     `[YEAR_MONTH_ID]=201701)=False))`
```

And this excludes too much, since all 201701 is removed:

```
WHERE [COMPANY_CODE] Not In (1001,1002,1003) And [YEAR_MONTH_ID] Not In (201701)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
WHERE ([COMPANY_CODE] Not In (1001,1002,1003) And [YEAR_MONTH_ID] Not In (201701))
```

Edit:

```
WHERE NOT ([COMPANY_CODE] In (1001,1002,1003) And [YEAR_MONTH_ID] In (201701))
```

Comment: It still removes all rows with 201701

Comment: Ok, WHERE NOT works. I now see that ACCESS changes the sql code when viewing the query in design mode. 

It changes to 
WHERE (((([COMPANY_CODE] In (1001,1002,1003)) And     `[YEAR_MONTH_ID]=201701)=False))` which gives an error when trying to run it.

Comment: Oh. Yes, the GUI designer has a few limitations. The good thing is, that if you correct the SQL and save the query, the SQL will stay fixed.